# Not able to ping remote server

Tags: remote-desktop, ping, tcpip

I am getting Request Time Out on pinging a remote server. I am on my laptop connected to the this server via Remote Desktop Connection.

tried but still not able to ping it. I just want to ellaborate a little as what am I doing as I dont have much idea in this thing. I am on my laptop connection to a windows server via remote desktop connection. On that server i pinged the ip address but it failed. from my laptop i pinged but failed.

Comment: Are you pinging by servername or IP-address?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your server will respond to ping requests. There's a great guide here: http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/20/how-to-enable-ping-in-windows-server-2012/ on how to enable it in Server 2012

Or for 2008: http://patrickyong.wordpress.com/2008/05/04/enable-ping-replies-on-windows-server-2008/

Either way, pings are blocked by default.

Comment: tried but still not able to ping it. I just want to ellaborate a little as what am I doing as I dont have much idea in this thing. I am on my laptop connection to a windows server via remote desktop connection. On that server i pinged the ip address but it failed. from my laptop i pinged but failed.

Comment: Can you ping it from an external source?

Comment: I followed the first blog post. At first I tried to enable the first `icmpv4` rule. But it fails to work for me. After enabling first two `icmpv4` rules, it works.